# Elm Make starts Windows Script Host and gives error?

Tags: elm

I'm playing in Elm, and whenever I use `elm make` I get an error from Windows Script Host:

[image]

The error states that there is an error in the build elm.js file. And when I look at the given line, it's the following:

```
return {
    keys: keys,     // A hash of key name to index
    free: free,     // An array of unkeyed item indices
} // line 10547
```

So I'm guessing it's bitching about the unneeded `,` on line 10546: `free: free,`.

But now my question is, why is Windows Script Host doing stuff with my build elm.js file anyway, and how can I fix it?

I already tried disabling Windows Script Host, but then I just get an error stating that it doesn't allow script to be run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a file in that directory called `elm.js`, the Windows Command Line tries executing that when you type `elm make`. It thinks you are intending this: `elm.js make`.

You can get around this in a few ways:

1. Change the name of the output file from `elm.js` to something else
2. Move the generated `elm.js` file to a subdirectory
3. Run `elm-make` from the command line instead of `elm make`
4. Use another shell like Powershell, Git Bash, or Cygwin

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm currently using suggestion 3 (`elm-make`), and haven't tried the others yet. So, to double chat that I understand it correctly, what is going wrong is that since I used the command `elm ...` in my command line, windows tries to find a file called `elm` and execute it. So now that I use `elm-make` windows will look for a file called `elm-make` and try to execute that, but now doesn't find anything. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The Windows Command Line assumes *.js files are executable and so it tries to run `elm.js` from the current directory as an executable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Was getting really annoyed at the Windows Script Host xD

Comment: Elm 0.19 dont have elm-make command.
Suggestion 4 doesn't work in my computer.
Suggestion 1&2 is the solution.

Comment: This worked for me:

Instead of using:
elm make src/Main.elm --output elm.js --debug

use:
elm make src/Main.elm --output target/elm.js --debug

This is an example of "Suggestion 2", in Chad Gilbert's answer.

I could not use "Suggestion 1" since elm did not approve of another name than *.js